# Spring Cloud AWS SQS fails to connect to service endpoint locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud's AWS SQS in a project I'm working on. At this time, I'm only running the application locally on my dev machine. Thus, what I want is to connect to the SQS on AWS without having to deploy my app to an EC2 instance.

However, it seems like the AWS SDK used in Spring Cloud's AWS package will attempt to authenticate through metadata and wants to resolve  `169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. Since I'm still the running the app locally, the endpoint cannot be resolved and an error is thrown:

```
2019-12-29 16:38:27.420  WARN 22462 --- [  restartedMain] com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/meta-data/instance-id). Failed to connect to service endpoint: 

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:62) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:400) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:369) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-aws-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.annotation.OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.matches(OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.java:37) ~[spring-cloud-aws-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:221) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
...
```

I've tried to explicitly supply an SQS endpoint in my bean, but it still attempts to connect to `169.254.169.254` resulting in the error above:

```
public AmazonSQSAsync sqsClient() {
   EndpointConfiguration endpointConfig = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
        "sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "us-east-1"
   );

   return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()))
                .build();
}
```

Although I'm not certain about this, I suspect that the error is occurring because I'm running the app locally on my dev machine and so it couldn't resolve to the endpoint. But I'm not entirely sure about this too because I'm running other AWS services in the same app using the AWS SDK and I don't have this error.

I've the following dependencies in my pom.xml and it appears that having any one of them will cause the error to occur. That's, I don't even have to create the beans to have that error. Adding these dependencies will immediately, for some reason, causes the SDK to attempt to resolve that endpoint and fail with that error.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

What else should I do to fix the error that it failed to connect to service endpoint?

Comment: Is your SQS has only IAM based access ?

Comment: @SauravKumarSingh I don’t think so. I don’t remember creating the SQS queue to restrict only to IAM access unless that’s the default configuration.

Comment: Use the Official AWS Java API over this 3rd party API to invoke AWS Services from within a Spring app. For starters, you will get support from the AWS Java SDK team.

Answer (score 27):

I have received below errors when running Spring Boot Project for AWS SNS

```
i.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher : Fail to retrieve token
com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document). Failed to connect to service endpoint:


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance

Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
```

Resolution applied:
Add below code snippet to SpringBootApplication & Click on Run Button in the IDE

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class,
                org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class,
                org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
```

Comment: I had the same problem running test profile; adding the same exclusions in the bootstrap-test.yml file solved the issue: (springboot 2.1.5 - springcloud 2.1.x)
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 19):

I know many people have already explained what's issue and how to skip this error. But, all the above method didn't work for me. Finally after lot of search I set following aws configuration property and it worked for me.

```
cloud.aws.region.use-default-aws-region-chain=true
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.credentials.access-key=
cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key=
cloud.aws.region.auto=false
cloud.aws.region.static=
cloud.aws.stack=false

logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error
logging.level.com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher=error
```

Comment: Just added the parameters  in IntelliJ run configuration and it works fine:

logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error
logging.level.com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher=error

Answer (score 16):

The following configuration worked for me:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      auto: false
      static: eu-west-1
      use-default-aws-region-chain: true
    stack: false
    stack.auto: false
logging:
  level:
    com:
      amazonaws:
        internal:
          InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher: error
        util:
          EC2MetadataUtils: error
```

Answer (score 9):

When using the AWS Java SDK outside of an EC2 instance, you can disable  loading credentials or regions from EC2 Metadata instance service with a [System property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/SDKGlobalConfiguration.html#AWS_EC2_METADATA_DISABLED_SYSTEM_PROPERTY) or an [Environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/SDKGlobalConfiguration.html#AWS_EC2_METADATA_DISABLED_ENV_VAR).

- System Property : `com.amazonaws.sdk.disableEc2Metadata`
- Environment variable : `AWS_EC2_METADATA_DISABLED`

However, you will still get a warning at application startup, it tells you the EC2Metadata is disabled by configuration : *"EC2 Instance Metadata Service is disabled"*

```
2020-03-27 18:10:42.483  WARN 71123 --- [main] com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/meta-data/instance-id). EC2 Instance Metadata Service is disabled

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: EC2 Instance Metadata Service is disabled
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:402)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38)
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Fix the problem adding in the application.yaml file:

```
logging:
  level:
    com:
      amazonaws:
        util:
          EC2MetadataUtils: error
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand its trying to check if your application is running on cloud environment, from the **5th last** line of the `stacktrace`

> org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironment(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38)

I checked out the the `repo` and here is the code snippet -

```
public static boolean isRunningOnCloudEnvironment() {
    if (isCloudEnvironment == null) {
        try {
            isCloudEnvironment = EC2MetadataUtils
                    .getData(EC2_METADATA_ROOT + "/instance-id", 1) != null;
        }
        catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            isCloudEnvironment = false;
        }
    }
    return isCloudEnvironment;
}
```

As per the snippet it tried to fetch instance `metadata` and if it fails it `return false`, which means you are not on the `Cloud Environment`. However this code is expected to Catch `AmazonClientException` but the **stacktrace** you shared is throwing `SdkClientException` exception, which this part of the snippet can't `catch` and hence can't return `false` that you are not on a cloud environment.

Seems like some issue with this build of the library, As per the stacktrace you are using `2.2.1.RELEASE1` which was released **9 days** back only. Could you please try to use one of the **older** version and then report if you are still facing the same issue.

---

Or as a temporary fix you can try **tunnelling** to your `VPC's entry server`. You can use [sshuttle](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for tunnelling purpose if you want. This will mostly make that IP reachable from local machine as well.

Comment: I've just tried using `2.2.0.RELEASE` but the same error is still occurring.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same kind of error when running s3 bucket in spring boot i solved using different location used while creating bucket:

```
   return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion("us-east-1")  //This is the code i added to fix 
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .build();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code so that it'd be easy to understand for others

Comment: https://github.com/arjun-sudo/AWS_Image_Upload Click here if you want to know in which project i got this error .

Answer (score 2):

1. Set `cloud.aws.region.auto` property to `false` in Spring application properties (or via environment variables etc.).
2. Define `cloud.aws.region.static` property.

This will tell Spring not to use automatic detection based EC2 meta data. Some [details](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__basic_setup.html#_configuring_region).

You may need to configure credentials similarly, you can find related info in the same doc.

Comment: I already have `cloud.aws.region.auto` set to false and `cloud.aws.region.static` set to my region but it seems like it's still attempting to retrieve from the EC2 meta data and resulting in the error.

Comment: These are the only options that influence on using meta data service. If they don’t work, then you have Spring bug. However this is basic functionality and there are many people who use it. From your question I don’t see you set these properties, the way how you build sqsClient is not the same as setting these options via property file.

Comment: It's in fact Spring bug. I experience the same problem now. Adding "cloud.aws.stack.auto=false" can be a workaround, however there are many warnings generated

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this? I am experiencing the same issue and have documented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271529/error-encountered-after-upgrading-to-spring-cloud-hoxton-sr7-from-hoxton-sr4.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the spring-cloud version Hoxton.SR8. Replace your spring-cloud version in your pom.xml with Finchley.SR1.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar error but not from the Spring cloud. When i added below configuration in application.properties, error went away.

logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error
logging.level.com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher=error

But i'm facing some other issues while opening s3a path. Then i printed the stacktrace of the exception and then i got below error

***Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [BasicAWSCredentialsProvider: Access key or secret key is null, WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider@7700439a: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]***

Already credentials are there /.aws folder but not sure why application still giving the error. Fixed by creating environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

This was coming from an internal dependency at my company, so I couldn't get any of the previously posted solutions to work.  What worked for me was to simply set in my environment variables AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'.